# Set the checked property using a compare statement (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm looking for a way to set the checked property based on an integer (not boolean in this case) inside an MVC view.

Is it possible to express this inside the view alone? (with our without an html helper is fine w/ me)

Comment: The checked property of what?

Comment: an html input of type checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard `if` clauses and such directly in the view:

```
<% if (myInt > 3) { %>
    <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">a checked box</input>
<% } else { %>
    <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox">a non-checked box</input>
<% } %>
```

Of course, Craig's version will look much nicer in your code... ;)

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox1", myInt > 3) %>
<label for="checkbox1">a box that might be checked...</label>
```

Note that you need the label tag to get a caption for your checkbox - the html helper doesn't give you that for free. Unless of course you use one of the [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox.aspx) which take an `IDictionary` of html attributes for an argument...

Comment: why is it that I overlook the obvious?  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: "My" version behaves differently, too. (Works with model binders due to hidden input.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.Checkbox("CheckboxName", someInt != 0) %>
```